# onClick change display on two different buttons (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I was trying to open a child Textura.js by showing results onClick in the parent Sofa.js. I manage to do display none or block based on the state it was before but now I need that I can also make display none on the Textura.js file onClick of the button on the child file.
Btw, ignore HideTextura code because it was just a try, doesn't work.

**Sofa.js** file, only important code:

```
const textura = <Textura />;

export class Sofa extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: false
        };
    }

    state = {
        showResults: false
    };

    showTextura = () => {
        const { grayscale1 } = this.state;
        this.setState(prev => ({
            showTextura: !prev.showTextura,
        }));
    }

    render() {

                return (
                    <div id="Sofa">

                        <div id="SpecCentro">
                             <img src="../../../ic/icon-tecido-azul.svg" className="Specs" onClick={this.showTextura} alt="Tecido" />
                        </div>

                        {this.state.showTextura ? textura : null}
                    </div>
                );

    }

}
```

**Textura.js** code, only important for this question:

```
export class Textura extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: this.props.display
        };
    }

    HideTextura = () => {
        const { display } = this.state;
        this.setState(prev => ({
            display: !display
        }));

    };

    render() {

        const { display } = this.state;

            return (
                <div style={{ display: display }} >
                    <button onClick={this.HideTextura}>
                        <img src="../../ic/icon-fechar.svg" alt="Fechar Módulo" id="OptionsClose" />
                    </button>

                    <div id="Options">

             /* content */

                    </div>
                </div>
            );

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? The question is vague

Comment: When I click on the button with the className="Spec" I make display block to the content on Textura.js. When I click again on the same button, it makes display none. What I want to do is that the button with id="OptionsClose" to make also display none to the Textura.js content @sagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `HideTextura` function from the `Textura` to the `Sofa` component and pass it down as a prop to the `Textura` component:

> I renamed it to `toggleTexture` and refactored your code a bit:

**Sofa.js file**

```
import Textura from '/path/to/Textura.js';    
export class Sofa extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showTextura: false
        };
    }

    toggleTextura = () => {
        const { showTextura } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            showTextura: !showTextura,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { showTextura } = this.state;
        return (
            <div id="Sofa">

                <div id="SpecCentro">
                     <img src="../../../ic/icon-tecido-azul.svg" className="Specs" onClick={this.toggleTextura} alt="Tecido" />
                </div>

                {showTextura ? <Textura toggleTextura={this.toggleTextura} /> : null}
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```

**Textura.js code**

```
export default class Textura extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { toggleTextura } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={toggleTextura}>
                    <img src="../../ic/icon-fechar.svg" alt="Fechar Módulo" id="OptionsClose" />
                </button>

                <div id="Options" onClick={toggleTextura}>

                </div>
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: The cross to close is the one that's gone, not div Options @LaurenzGlück

Comment: If you want to close it on clicking the id="OptionsClose", just add the `onClick={toggleTextura}` to the div (I edited my answer)

Comment: Nothing works, nor opening or closing in any buttons

Comment: I think this is why it doesn't work {showTextura ? <Textura toggleTextura={this.toggleTextura} /> : null} and also the display changes what?

Comment: Okay - sorry there is a little bug: The state var need to be called `showTextura` and not `display`

Comment: @soalribeiro Here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lpwymnz2kl

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
class Sofa extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  toggleTextura = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      show: !previousState.show
    }))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src="con-tecido-azul.svg" className="Specs" onClick={this.toggleTextura} />
        {
          this.state.show ? <Textura handler={this.toggleTextura} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}
export default Sofa;
```

**textura.js**

```
const Textura = ({handler}) => (
   <button onClick={handler} / >
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:false` and `display:true` is it correct in css???

```
style={(this.state.display===true ? {display:block} :{display:none})}
```

hope it will help